# MVC3 Why is my posted model NULL?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Curious issue with MVC3, EF Code First.

I'm passing a model that wraps two models to a view.

```
 public class UserInfoModel
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// <para>Corresponds to ProviderUserKey in ASP Membership</para>
    /// <para>Used in Membership.GetUser(ProviderUserKey) to retrieve email and username.</para>
    /// </summary>
    public Guid MembershipId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "First name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Last name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Address 1")]
    public string Address1 { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Address 2")]
    public string Address2 { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "State")]
    public string State { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Country")]
    public string Country { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Zip code")]
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    [Display(Name = "Phone number")]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "Sign up date")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = @"{0:MM/dd\/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime SignUpDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "Birthday")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = @"{0:MM\/dd\/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "Enrollment date")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = @"{0:MM\/dd\/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.ImageUrl)]
    [Display(Name = "Avatar")]
    public string AvatarImage { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Rank")]
    public int RankId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("RankId")]
    public UserRankModel Rank { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "IsActive")]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

}

public class RegisterModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}

public class UserInfoAndRegisterModel
{
    public UserInfoModel UserInfoModel { get; set; }
    public RegisterModel RegisterModel { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model K2Calendar.Models.UserInfoAndRegisterModel
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Update User";
}
<div class="container">
    <h2>
        Update Account Details</h2>
    <p>
        Use the form below to update the account.
    </p>
    <p>
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Account update was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.")
    </p>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript">    </script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.UserInfoModel.Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.UserInfoModel.MembershipId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.UserInfoModel.SignUpDate) 
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span6">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RegisterModel.UserName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.RegisterModel.UserName, new { tabindex = "1" , disabled = "disabled" } )
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.RegisterModel.UserName)
        </div>
        <div class="span6">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserInfoModel.State)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserInfoModel.State, new { tabindex = "8" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserInfoModel.State)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span6">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RegisterModel.Email)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.RegisterModel.Email, new { tabindex = "2" , disabled = "disabled" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.RegisterModel.Email)
        </div>
        <div class="span6">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserInfoModel.ZipCode)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserInfoModel.ZipCode, new { tabindex = "9" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserInfoModel.ZipCode)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span6"> 
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserInfoModel.FirstName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserInfoModel.FirstName, new { tabindex = "3" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserInfoModel.FirstName)
        </div>
        <div class="span6">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserInfoModel.Country)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserInfoModel.Country, new { tabindex = "10" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserInfoModel.Country)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span6">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserInfoModel.LastName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserInfoModel.LastName, new { tabindex = "4" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserInfoModel.LastName)
        </div>
        <div class="span6">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserInfoModel.BirthDate)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserInfoModel.BirthDate, new { tabindex = "11", placeholder = "mm/dd/yyyy" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserInfoModel.BirthDate)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span6">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserInfoModel.Address1)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserInfoModel.Address1, new { tabindex = "5" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserInfoModel.Address1)
        </div>
        <div class="span6">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserInfoModel.EnrollmentDate)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserInfoModel.EnrollmentDate, new { tabindex = "12", placeholder = "mm/dd/yyyy" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserInfoModel.EnrollmentDate)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span6">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserInfoModel.Address2)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserInfoModel.Address2, new { tabindex = "6" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserInfoModel.Address2)
        </div>
        <div class="span6">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserInfoModel.RankId)
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.UserInfoModel.RankId, (SelectList)ViewBag.RankList, new { tabindex = "13" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span6">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserInfoModel.PhoneNumber)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserInfoModel.PhoneNumber, new { tabindex = "7" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserInfoModel.PhoneNumber)
        </div>
        <div class="span6">

        </div>
    </div>

    <br />
    <p>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" tabindex = "14">Update &raquo;</button>
    </p>
}
```

My controller classes takes the model that is posted and does some db updates.

One of the wrapped models is null:

```
[Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(UserInfoAndRegisterModel model)
    {
        //WHY IS model.RegisterModel == null ??//
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                dbContext.Entry(model.UserInfoModel).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
                dbContext.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to update UserInfoModel", ex.InnerException);
            }
        }
        GenerateRanksList();
        return View(model);
    }
```

I do the same thing for the account creation and I do not receive a null value for RegisterModel with almost identical view code.

Currently this is a non-issue in that I only update the UserInfoModel currently but in the future I may want to allow a user to change their email address or user name.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Your `RegisterModel` is null because you are not posting any values which belongs to the `RegisterModel`

Although you have inputs which belong to `RegisterModel` like this in your view

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.RegisterModel.UserName, 
                 new { tabindex = "1" , disabled = "disabled" } )
```

They are all `disabled` and disabled inputs are not posted:

[Form submission - Successful controls](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2)

> A successful control is "valid" for submission
>
> However:
>
> Controls that are disabled cannot be successful.

So you need remove the `disable` or add the properties as hidden fields:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.RegisterModel.UserName)
```

Comment: You are 100% correct.  Removing 'the disabled' made the model non-null.  With the code posted I assumed I would have been getting a non-null model filled with null properties.